# Cordova - Logic behind onDeviceReady Event Listener

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm following this tutorial: https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/articles/cordova-core-plugin-camera-short-code-example

It works perfectly fine on my iPhone 5s running iOS 10 with Cordova 6.5.0

However, I don't understand the Logic behind when and what must be placed inside a function that is called when the device is ready.

As you can see, onDeviceReady is called when the device is ready:

document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

```
// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
    destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
}
```

But other API-Calls like taking the actual picture don't require that step (a function that can be called as soon as the button calling it is visible):

```
// A button will call this function
//
function capturePhoto() {
  // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
  navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
    destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
}
```

Putting the content of the onDeviceReady function inside the capturePhoto function and waiting several seconds after the page loaded completely breaks the whole thing - why?

Also, why does `navigator.camera.DestinationType` differ from the official tutorial which wants you to use `Camera.DestinationType`?

### What I learned so far from the responses

#### Please correct me, if I got something wrong

Whenever a javascript cordova function is called as soon as the DOM loads it can happen that the native cordova code is not yet ready. But by putting that code inside a onDocumentReady function you can bypass that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `deviceready` event is fired after the Cordova APIs are loaded/initialized. If you are using a function from the Cordova API, the best way to guarantee that it has loaded and is thus ready to use, is to only initiate your application logic once the libraries have loaded. I.e. use `deviceready` to "initialize" your application.

This is analogous to trying to access an `HTMLElement` before the document has loaded (for example, to bind an event handler).

E.g.

```
class App
{
    constructor() {
        console.log("Loaded!");

        this.bindEvents = this.bindEvents.bind(this);
        this.click = this.click.bind(this);
    }

    bindEvents() {
        document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', this.click);
    }

    click() {
        navigator.camera.getPicture(...);
    }
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => {
    // Do all bindings here / start using API.
    let app = new App();
    app.bindEvents();
}, false);
```

The reason your "button" works and is starting the camera, is because you happen to be waiting long enough once your app starts up before clicking the button. You can try click the "button" as fast as possible once your app starts. It's possible you'll click it before the device is ready (depends on how long it takes).

Regarding your specific code, all you're doing is creating an "alias" for the Camera API.

Comment: But why doesn't it work when the code from inside the onDeviceReady function is inside the 'button function' and I wait the same amount of time? the device should be ready by then?

Comment: You're not using `pictureSource`, at least in the code you provided, so that won't make a difference. Try use `navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL` instead of `destinationType`. My guess would be that the problem is not in the code you supplied, assuming you _ensure_ that you invoke `capturePhoto` after deviceready has fired.

Comment: Whatever I did before, it now works prefectly (with `destinationType`) - But since you mentioned it what's the difference between `navigator.camera.destinationType` (Intel Tutorial) and `Camera.DestinationType` (Apache Tutorial)

Comment: btw, it's `DestinationType` - case-sensitive. The "constants" are officially defined in the Camera object. All the Camera constants are "exported" to `navigator.camera` so that you can access them. I.e. it's made public. Take a look at the source [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/www/Camera.js#L38).

Answer (score 0):

onDeviceReady event is fired once after full initialization of cordova. When using plugins, all you need to do is to make sure that your call to plugin interface takes place after onDeviceReady() event was catched. You don't need to wait for it every time you need to use plugin. There are other events worth mentioning, here you can read something about cordova application lifecycle: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html

Just try to catch different events and print out some console logs to see when different events are fired (good learning technique btw).

When using plugins calls, you need to use namespace where plugin functon is hooked. Sometimes these functions are accessible from different objects, thats why there are some inconsequences in tutorials. To make sure you will call what you want, you can always look to plugin documentation or to plugin www directory, where you can find javascript interface file.

Comment: But the tutorial on the Intel page and the 'official' cordova tutorial are using the same plugin - why the difference?

Comment: Make a quick test: log `Camera` object and `navigator.camera` and look what have you got. If the objects got the same interface, then there is no differece at all. Differences sometimes comes from versions of plugins, and sometimes there are a few ways to get to the plugin interface and thats all. Nothing to worry actually,

Comment: That's actually a whole different topic :/ I couldn't figure out just yet where the console.log() logs are stored when I use the iOS Simulator or the actual device... I'm not using XCode to test - should I?

Comment: You can, but there are other ways to debug your app. If you are working on Windows you can use `chrome://inspect` to debug your app. Similar (but not that complex) functionality you have in Safari  `Development -> <your device> -> index.html.` There you can see console logs and errors from application runing on simulator/real device. Also there are logs when you are working in some IDE such as NetBeans (with cordova plugin) or XCode.

Comment: I just tried replacing `navigator.camera` with `Camera` and it works fine. If I could, I'd upvote your reply. - But my device does not show up in Safari - It's connected via USB and runs the App I created with `cordova run ios --device`